# Can a function have its maximum value other than at the maxima given by calculus?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

Suppose we have a continuous and differentiable function $f(x,y)$ defined on $x^{2}+y^{2} \leq 1$.
Let's say this function has a maxima  at some point $r$ *inside* this region, that is, in $x^2 + y^2<1$.

**My question:** If this function has **no** extrema (that is it's derivatives don't go to zero anywhere except at $r$) except the one specified above in this region ,is it possible for the function to have a greater value in this region than the maxima we had above?.

Comment: By inside do you mean $x^2 + y^2 <1$?

Comment: Yes, inside the circle.

Comment: The disk is compact so the function will have a minimum and maximum value (the Extreme Value Theorem). The extrema may be on the boundary. The function may have other local extrema anywhere. One (or more if there are ties) of the local maxima will be the global maximum, one (or more) of the local minima will be the global minimum.

Comment: Presumably $f$ is not only continuous but also differentiable

Comment: @MPW, thank you.I've edited it. I'm not used to so much rigour.

Comment: @Samuel, so there is a possibility of having a greater value than the given maxima?

Comment: There's a possibility of it having maxima (and minima) elsewhere if you're only specifying that *some* maximum occurs within the disk, yes. You'd have to specify that that maximum was a (one of) global maxima if that's what you meant

Comment: @redroid, I only know that this function has a Maxima inside the disk say at $r$, I don't know if it's global or not. I want to know that, can this function have a greater value on this disk than our known maxima ,given that the derivatives only go to zero at $r$?

Comment: No, if you know that the derivatives are only zero at one point, then that point is the only possible maxima

Comment: A maximum in the interior found using derivative tests is a local maximum. The global maximum need not be found this way, for instance if it occurs on the boundary. (Imagine a plane inclined at an angle with a teensy bump in the middle. The little bump is a local maximum but the global maximum would still occur on the boundary.)